# SQL Exception when executing stored procedure from within Biztalk

Tags: sql-server, ssis, biztalk

We have a stored procedure in place that creates a new SSIS execution and starts it:

```
Declare @execution_id bigint

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
    @package_name=N'00 XXXX.dtsx', 
    @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, 
    @folder_name=N'XX', 
    @project_name=N'XXX';

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id;
```

When we call this stored procedure logged on using SQL Server Management Studio, this works perfectly. However, when we execute this stored procedure from within BizTalk (as a BTS service account user) we receive this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '-'.
>   Incorrect syntax near '-'.
>   Incorrect syntax near '-'.
>
> Server stack trace:
>   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
>   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)

The schema we use from BTS to MS SQL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <annotation>
    <appinfo>
      <fileNameHint xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/xsd">TypedProcedure.dbo</fileNameHint>
    </appinfo>
  </annotation>
  <element name="StartBifImport">
    <annotation>
      <documentation>
        <doc:action xmlns:doc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/documentation">TypedProcedure/dbo/StartBifImport</doc:action>
      </documentation>
    </annotation>
    <complexType>
      <sequence />
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

The BTS service account has the db_owner role on the database where the stored procedure resides, and we have given it explicitly all 'grant' permissions on the SSIS folder and SSIS package.

We can see in the executions table that no execution is created, so something seems to go wrong on that call. When connecting with SQL Profiler we see the same error returning, but without much further context as to what is wrong; leaving is without much trace.

Any pointers/ideas on how the debug or resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you running this through a Send Port or helper class?

Comment: Through a Send Port (schema based). The call to the stored procedure itself works, since when we call it with the contents place in comments it executes without any problems.

Comment: Can you perhaps show us what the schema looks like?

Comment: I added the schema to my initial question. The schema message validates against the schema. When we remove everything from the stored proc, it works just fine.

Comment: Try using SQL Server PRofiler to capture the actual SQL call that gets generated, see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not to use a "Strongly-Typed Procedure" schema, but a "Procedure" schema. The "Strongly-Typed Procedure" from the WCF-SQL adapter has a documented issue with generating the schema for stored procedures with temp tables in it.

The SQL adapter does not support generating metadata for strongly-typed stored procedures that contain temporary tables in their definition. Instead, you should generate metadata for the same procedure from under the Procedures node while using the Add Adapter Service Reference Plug-in or Consume Adapter Service Add-in.

More information can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788435(BTS.10).aspx#BKMK_SQLMetadataStronglyTyped

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple one-way send port that has the same filter (and map, if applicable) as one you are busy debugging, that simply writes to a file. Use the output of the file to confirm the message sent to the WCF-SQL adaptor has the structure it is expecting.

Judging by the schema, it should produce a file with the following content:

```
<ns0:StartBifImport xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo">
</ns0:StartBifImport>
```

Comment: We already checked this. The message validates correctly against the schema (and corresponds to the above). When we remove everything from the stored procedure, the call from BTS works just fine.

Comment: And opening SSMS via Run as different user, and using the BizTalk service account, and then executing `EXEC StartBifImport` in SSMS executes successfully?

Comment: Run biztalk again and use SQL Server Profiler to catch the exact sql statement called from biztalk server to SQL.

Comment: Our stored procedure is called 'StartBifImport'. Using SQL Profiler we can see the call to this stored proc:  "exec [dbo].[StartBifImport]". We can see this stored procedure is being executed by the BTS user.

Comment: Just to confirm, [StartBifImport] does indeed live in the [dbo] schema, and is correct? (I noticed [create_execution] sits in [catalog].)

Comment: We have a database 'BIF' where the stored procedure [StartBifImport] lives in the [dbo] schema. From that stored proc we call [catalog].[start_execution] in the [SSISDB] DB.